# MongoDB find minimum and maximum between grouped data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Will try to keep this concise with the input, result and desired/expected result. Need to find the minimum, maximum number of rows/records between the same "winCode" and the last time it occurred in the ordered data. So it makes me want to first group them by "winCode" which works perfectly, but I am not able to come up with something that would display how many records it took for the same "winCode" to appear last time, the minimum and maximum. Check desired output for more details. Below is the paste from: https://mongoplayground.net/p/bCzTO8ZLxNi

Input/collection

```
[
  {
    code: "1",
    results: {
      winCode: 3
    }
  },
  {
    code: "10",
    results: {
      winCode: 3
    }
  },
  {
    code: "8",
    results: {
      winCode: 2
    }
  },
  {
    code: "5",
    results: {
      winCode: 5
    }
  },
  {
    code: "5",
    results: {
      winCode: 4
    }
  },
  {
    code: "6",
    results: {
      winCode: 4
    }
  },
  {
    code: "7",
    results: {
      winCode: 5
    }
  },
  {
    code: "3",
    results: {
      winCode: 3
    }
  },
  {
    code: "9",
    results: {
      winCode: 2
    }
  },
  {
    code: "2",
    results: {
      winCode: 2
    }
  }
]
```

Current query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      code: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$results.winCode",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      lastTimeOccurredCode: {
        $first: "$code" // Any way to get it to display a count from the start to this point on how many records it went through to get the $first result?
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: -1
    }
  },
  
])
```

Current output

```
[
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "count": 2,
    "lastTimeOccurredCode": "5"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "count": 2,
    "lastTimeOccurredCode": "5"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "count": 3,
    "lastTimeOccurredCode": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "count": 3,
    "lastTimeOccurredCode": "2"
  }
]
```

Desired output

```
[
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "count": 2,
    "lastTimeOccurredRecordsCount": 4,
    "minRecordsBetween": 3,
    "maxRecordsBetween": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "count": 2,
    "lastTimeOccurredRecordsCount": 5,
    "minRecordsBetween": 1,
    "maxRecordsBetween": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "count": 3,
    "lastTimeOccurredRecordsCount": 1,
    "minRecordsBetween": 1,
    "maxRecordsBetween": 6
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "count": 3,
    "lastTimeOccurredRecordsCount": 3,
    "minRecordsBetween": 1,
    "maxRecordsBetween": 6
  }
]
```

I have tried to add an $accumulator function, but I would need the $first functions result in it, but it's not available at the same $group stage. Feel like I am missing something here.

Comment: The min and max records between should be according to which sort condition?

Comment: @nimrodserok in my case it's `-1` but it doesn't matter much as long as the logic is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$setWindowFields` to define index and reduce to find the diff between them. If you want the index to be according to `{$sort: {code: -1}}`, then keep the `$setWindowFields` sortBy according to this example and remove the redundant `{$sort: {code: -1}}` step. If you want the index to be according to another sorting logic that only update the `$setWindowFields` sortBy.

1. Use `$setWindowFields` to define index
2. `$sort` according to your what you need (if it is different than the prev sort)
3. `$group` according to the `$results.winCode` and keep all index data.
4. Calculate the `diff`
5. Format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {code: -1},
      output: {index: {$sum: 1, window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}}}
  }},
  {$sort: {code: -1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$results.winCode",
      count: {$sum: 1},
      lastTimeOccurredCode: {$first: "$code"},
      index: {$push: "$index"}
  }},
  {$project: {
      count: 1,
      lastTimeOccurredCode: 1,
      diff: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {$range: [1, {$size: "$index"}]},
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [{$subtract: [
                    {$arrayElemAt: ["$index", "$$this"]},
                    {$arrayElemAt: ["$index", {$subtract: ["$$this", 1]}]}
              ]}]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
  }},
  {$set: {
      minRecordsBetween: {$min: "$diff"},
      maxRecordsBetween: {$max: "$diff"},
      diff: "$$REMOVE"
  }},
  {$sort: {_id: -1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aARNcp6-JdA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and an example! It looks perfect, I'm impressed by how fast you completed this to be honest. Out of curiosity, did it take long for you to achieve this level of proficiency with MongoDB? I've just started using it and while writing similar logic in JS was easy for me, in Mongo it seemed like a jungle and it feels hard to find all the things in the documentation somehow.

Comment: Happy to help. It is a syntax like any other syntax. If you write in different languages, this is just like any other. Each has its own limitations and conventions to be efficient. I'm working with mongoDB for 7 years now...So for me it is easy :)

Comment: True, all in all they all achieve a similar thing, just with slight variations. It just means my base knowledge is lacking in this area, and it's not a problem of a variation. 7 years is a lot, still nothing short of impressive for me in how fast you tackled this issue, thanks again! :)